# Linux-distro with built-in Xen?

Tags: linux, distributions, virtualization, xen

Are there any Linux-distros with Xen "built-in" and ready to act as host for virtual-computer out-of-the-box?  Alternatively, distros where you can easily select "Xen-host" as an install option?  I'm after setting-up a Xen-host as easily as possible...

Comment: you might have an easier time using KVM and just installing `virt-manager`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Any of these](http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/Dom0_Kernels_for_Xen#Linux_Distributions_which_have_a_Xen_Dom0_kernel) (although the full list is a bit out of date).

> ### Linux Distributions which have a Xen Dom0 kernel
>
> ```
> Distributions     Versions
> Alpine Linux    2.4.x[2]
> Debian  4.0 (Etch), 5.0 (Lenny), 6.0 (Squeeze)[1]
> Fedora  15 (Lovelock)[3], 16 (Verne), 17 (Beefy Miracle)[1]
> Linux Mint  13, 14 [4]
> OpenSUSE    10.x, 11.x, 12.x
> Oracle VM for x86 (OVS)     All versions
> Redhat Enterprise Linux (RHEL)  5.x
> CentOS and other RHEL clones    5.x
> SUSE Linux Enterprise Server (SLES)     10.x, 11.x
> Ubuntu  11.10[1], 12.04 LTS[1]
> Xen Cloud Project (XCP)     All versions
> XenServer   All versions
>
> [1] Please note that this kernel requires Xen >= 4.0.
> [2] See wiki for more info
> [3] Dom0 kernel provided via this (unofficial) repository
> [4] Based on Ubuntu 12.04 and 12.10 resp.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu (12.04) Xen is not installed by default. But after an installation it can be easily added by using:

```
sudo apt-get install xen-utils-common
```

with the ease nowadays of installing packages and the number of combinations of what is possible, it is kind of difficult to provide a seperate distribution for every combination of useful things beyond the basics. You can roll your own distribution of course that includes what **you** want.